# Curl not working with Content-Type

Tags: php, curl, header

I have following piece of code:

```
$input = http_build_query(array('text' => 'hello'));
$url = "http://localhost/deskline/server.php";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $input);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain', 'Content-Length:'.strlen($input)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
```

And in the server.php file this code:

```
echo $_POST['text'];
```

Whenever I load the php file which should echo out the text (hello), nothing happens unless I remove the 'Content-Type: text/plain' from the header. I tried using 'text/html' insted but it didn't help at all.

I'll be very grateful for every piece of advice.

Thank you

Comment: please add contents of `http://localhost/deskline/server.php` file in question.

Comment: I have already done it. It just echoes $_POST['text']

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add an additional curl_setopt statement to make this a POST request.

Add the following:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

Comment: It didn't fix the problem

Comment: does [curl_errno](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) return anything? Have you tried the same request with a REST Client?

Comment: Also, are you posting plain text, or are you posting a query string containing some key-value pairs?  content-type tells the server how to handle the data in postfields, and if you tell it this is a human readable string (text/plain), how does it know how to parse your keys and values from it?